# Catch Is Not Being Executed - Is There Another Place It Should Be?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having a hard time figuring how to fix my code  . When I run it and the connection with the server is terminated the application stops the poll  . I added Catch to log the issue but it does not get there ....
Is there any idea how to fix this and be able to get the diffrent errors  .
Below is my code many many thanks for everyone who can fix this  .

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, tap, mergeMap, repeat, takeUntil, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>(); // Subject for unsubscribing
  public  curState;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  display = response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.curState=response;
  };

  poll = of({}).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => this.pollOmni()),catchError(err => {
      console.log("error captured");throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err; 
    }),
    tap(this.display),
    delay(200),
    repeat(),
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe), // Unsubscribe when ngUnsubscribe emits
  );

  pollOmni() {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://127.0.0.1:8084/api', { call: 'getInfo' });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.poll.subscribe();
    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next(); // Emit value to unsubscribe from ongoing subscriptions
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete(); // Complete the subject
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your http call is returning an error code?  Your code works fine in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76615815?devtoolsHeight=80&file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Answer (score 1):

I have the three following suggestions:

1. To catch the error emitted from the HTTP request, try to pipe the `catchError` directly to the respective observable.
2. I'm not sure if the HTTP observable emits an error when the connection to the server gets terminated. To ensure that it does, you could use the `timeout` operator to emit an error after a defined time.
3. Using `of({})` + `delay(200)` + `repeat` combination for polling an HTTP request looks dirty. Instead you could use [`timer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer) + `switchMap`.

Bonus suggestion ([Source](https://twitter.com/michael_hladky/status/1193641068635590656?lang=en)):

> A subject with no subscribers is just a function.
> NO NEED TO COMPLETE!

```js
const HTTP_POLL_INTERVAL = 200; // in ms
const HTTP_REQ_TIMEOUT = 5000; // in ms

poll = timer(0, HTTP_POLL_INTERVAL).pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    this.pollOmni().pipe(
      timeout(HTTP_REQ_TIMEOUT),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log("error captured");
        throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err; 
      })
    )
  ),
  tap(this.display),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
);

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe.next(); // <-- `.complete()` is not needed here
}
```